# iPython runs on Python 3 instead of Python 2

Tags: ipython

I've installed iPython via pip.  However, it runs on Python 3.  How do I get my system to differentiate between iPython and iPython3?  I'd like iPython to run on Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPython is a python3 script itself so go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

and change `python3` into the default `python` and it'll run Python 2.

If that doesn't work, ensure you've got [a compatible version](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-4:-Python-3-Compatibility) of Python and iPython.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've installed IPython 6.x, this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333223/4518341) from Stack Overflow is relevant:

---

IPython 6+ requires Python 3.3+, so that's what it defaults to, and it will not open Python 2.x.

From the [6.x Series page](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html) in the IPython docs:

> #### Important
>
> This documentation covers IPython versions 6.0 and higher. Beginning
> with version 6.0, IPython stopped supporting compatibility with Python
> versions lower than 3.3 including all versions of Python 2.7.
>
> If you are looking for an IPython version compatible with Python 2.7,
> please use the IPython 5.x LTS release and refer to its documentation
> (LTS is the long term support release).